# python re.sub newline multiline dotall

Tags: python, replace, newline, multiline

I have this CSV with the next lines written on it (please note the newline /n):

```
"<a>https://google.com</a>",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,Dirección
```

I am trying to delete all that commas and putting the address one row up. Thus, on Python I am using this:

```
with open('Reutput.csv') as e, open('Put.csv', 'w') as ee:
    text = e.read()
    text = str(text)
    re.compile('<a/>*D', re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    replace = re.sub('<a/>*D','<a/>",D',text) #arreglar comas entre campos
    replace = str(replace)
    ee.write(replace)
f.close()
```

As far as I know, re.multiline and re.dotall are necessary to fulfill /n needs. I am using re.compile because it is the only way I know to add them, but obviously compiling it is not needed here.

How could I finish with this text?

```
"<a>https://google.com</a>",Dirección
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need the compile statement at all, because you aren't using it.  You can put either the compiled pattern or the raw pattern in the re.sub function.  You also don't need the MULTILINE flag, which has to do with the interpretation of the ^ and $ metacharacters, which you don't use.

The heart of the problem is that you are compiling the flag into a regular expression pattern, but since you aren't using the compiled pattern in your substitute command, it isn't getting recognized.

One more thing.  re.sub returns a string, so `replace = str(replace)` is unnecessary.

Here's what worked for me:

```
import re
with open('Reutput.csv') as e:
    text = e.read()
    text = str(text)
    s = re.compile('</a>".*D',re.DOTALL)
    replace = re.sub(s, '</a>"D',text) #arreglar comas entre campos
    print(replace)
```

If you just call re.sub without compiling, you need to call it like

`re.sub('</a>".*D', '</a>"D', text, flags=re.DOTALL)`

I don't know exactly what your application is, of course, but if all you want to do is to delete all the commas and newlines, it might be clearer to write

```
replace = ''.join((c for c in text if c not in ',\n'))
```

Comment: Your solution runs smoothly ! :) Thank you for your explanations Saul; I really appreciate them. Best wishes

Comment: @Alfredo Bueno If your problem is solved, you should accept one of the answers by giving it a green checkmark.  That will help anyone who refers to your question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

When you use re.compile you need to save the returned [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) object and then call sub on that. You also need to have a .* to match any character instead of matching close html tags. The re.MULTILINE flag is only for the begin and end string symbols (^ and $) so you do not need it in this case.

```
regex = re.compile('</a>.*D',re.DOTALL)
replace = regex.sub('</a>",D',text)
```

That should work. You don't need to convert replace to a string since it is already a string.

Alternative you can write a regular expression that doesn't use .

```
replace = re.sub('"(,|\n)*D','",D',text)
```

Comment: Absolutely yes. Furthermore thanks to your answer I understand quit better how re works. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using re.sub with multiline texte

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

output = open("newFile.txt","w")
input = open("myfile.txt")
file = input.read()
input.close()

text = input.read()
replace = re.sub("value1\n\s +nickname", "value\n\s +name", text, flags=re.DOTALL)
output.write(replace)
output.close()
```